# What is the Lua equivalent of int(input())?

Tags: python, input, lua, integer

I'm asking the user for a number using

```lua
var = io.read()
```

and then when I do

```lua
if var == 1 then
    print ("Thing One")
elseif var == 2 then
    print ("Thing Two")
else
    print ("Thing Three")
```

This always returns "Thing Three" I am presuming this means I need var to get an integer, like when python uses `int(input())`

Comment: I see no shouting... :P

Comment: @user3078240 Do **not** use `#`. Its intended use is for long questions/answers that require multiple sections. Do not overuse formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Lua supports an argument to [`io.read()`](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.3.html) call. You can pass `*n` or `*number` as a string to it so that your input would be a number or `nil`.

```lua
print "enter a number:"
n = io.read("*number")
if not n then error("invalid input") end
```

You should also take a light reading of [this page of PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html).

---

So, your code shall be:

```lua
var = io.read( "*n" ) -- or io.read( "*number" )

if var == 1 then
    print ("Thing One")
elseif var == 2 then
    print ("Thing Two")
else
    print ("Thing Three")
end
```